# Microsoft Flow: Why is my multiple condition not working

Tags: microsoft-flow, if-condition

I am using modern SharePoint and have set my flow to trigger when an item is created or modified.

Where I'm getting stuck is the conditioning as I have two conditions that need to be met:
1) The Y/N column "UATguide" is true.
2) The choice column "SOXcomplete" is Yes.

When I try to use the expression below, I get an "invalid expression error".

```
@and(equals(triggerBody()?[‘UATguide’], true), @equals(triggerBody()?[‘SOXcomplete’]?[‘Value’], ‘Yes’))
```

I'm sure it's a syntax thing, but I'm not seeing it. Any assistance would be appreciated as I'm new to multiple conditions in a flow.

[image: Screenshot of flow]

Comment: I've also found this.. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Multiple-Flow-Conditions/td-p/31510 but where I work we don't have the edit in advanced mode so I can "grab the condition syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the expression builder to type this out. Is there a reason you aren't using the UI to build your conditions?

It looks like in your expression one of the equals starts with @ and one doesn't. Not sure which is right, but they should be the same. I think that using the UI should build it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need a false value on the right. like:

```
if(equals(item()['EMPLOYMENT_TYPE'], 'FT'), 'True', 'False')
```